# behavior of the selectiv flag

Tags: python, telegram-bot

there is a code that generates a keyboard in the telegram bot for users (group and personal buttons via the select parameter all work fine before trying to switch the types of buttons
this is the code for generating personal buttons

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['button', 'b'])
def handle_button_command(message):
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    button_text = message.text..replace('/button', '').replace('@rimdlav1bot', '').replace('/b', '').strip()

    if button_text:
        if user_id in user_keyboards:
            user_keyboards[user_id].append(button_text)
        else:
            user_keyboards[user_id] = [button_text]
        if len(user_keyboards[user_id]) > 12:
            columns = 4
        elif len(user_keyboards[user_id]) > 8:
            columns = 3
        else:
            columns = 2
        keyboard_buttons = []
        for row in chunks(user_keyboards[user_id], columns):
            keyboard_buttons.append(row)
        bot.send_message(chat_id, f'The "{button_text}" button has been added!', reply_markup=json.dumps(
            {'keyboard': keyboard_buttons, 'resize_keyboard': True, 'selective': True}),
                         reply_to_message_id=message.message_id)
    else:
        bot.send_message(chat_id, 'Please enter the text for the button')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['switch'])
def handle_switch_command(message):
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    current_state = user_states.get(user_id, 'group')
    if current_state == 'group':
        user_states[user_id] = 'personal'
        personal_buttons = user_keyboards.get(user_id, [])
        print(f"Personal buttons for user {user_id}: {personal_buttons}")
        personal_keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, selective=True)
        if personal_buttons:
            buttons = [types.KeyboardButton(text) for text in personal_buttons]
            personal_keyboard.add(*buttons)
        print(f"Generated personal keyboard for user {user_id}: {personal_keyboard}")
        bot.send_message(chat_id, 'You switched to personal buttons.', reply_markup=personal_keyboard)
    else:
        user_states[user_id] = 'group'
        global_keyboard = generate_group_buttons()
        if not global_keyboard:
            bot.send_message(chat_id, 'The chat doesn't have buttons yet.')
        else:
            bot.send_message(chat_id, 'You have switched to group buttons.', reply_markup=global_keyboard)
```

and this is the code for switching to group

I tried different options and the buttons work correctly without the selective parameter, but when you install it, the buttons simply stop being output